# Apache nutch compatibility with ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nutch

I am setting up system for Apache Nutch, but i am stuck with operating system. I am confused which version of ubuntu is compatible with Apache Nutch 2.3.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any version of Ubuntu should play fine with Nutch, you should just need a running JVM. In my experience, usually installing the JRE/JDK and setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the shell with the right value is enough to get you running Nutch in local mode.